# Difference between add_lvalue_reference_t<T> and T&

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, generic-programming

Suppose you have a template argument `T`.

What are the differences between

- `add_cv_t<T>` and `const volatile T`
- `add_const_t<T>` and `const T`
- `add_volatile_t<T>` and `volatile T`
- `add_lvalue_reference_t<T>` and `T&`
- `add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` and `T&&`
- `add_pointer_t<T>` and `T*`?

Why should I use `add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` instead of `T&&` for example. Are there any rules when to choose which?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> - `add_cv_t<T>` and `const volatile T`
> - `add_const_t<T>` and `const T`
> - `add_volatile_t<T>` and `volatile T`

No difference; the definition of `add_const<T>::type` is just `T const`, for example.

> - `add_lvalue_reference_t<T>` and `T&`
> - `add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` and `T&&`

`T&` and `T&&` are ill-formed when `T` is *cv* `void`, but these templates are well-formed, just giving the original type back.

> - `add_pointer_t<T>` and `T*`?

`add_pointer_t<T>` is equivalent to `std::remove_reference<T>::type*`. That is, if `T` is a reference type, it gives a pointer to the referenced type. On the other hand, `T*` will be ill-formed since you cannot have a pointer to a reference.

Which should you use?

- In general, the alias templates can be used to prevent deduction of `T`. Of course, that means that if you want deduction, you should avoid them.
- The alias templates can be used as template template arguments to a template that takes a type transformation as a parameter.
- The alias templates that differ in behaviour from alternatives like `T*` are useful in generic code since they "do the right thing". For example, if `T` is deduced from an argument of type `T&&`, then `T*` does the wrong thing when the argument is an lvalue, since it tries to declare a pointer to an lvalue reference. But `std::add_pointer_t<T>` will give a pointer to the actual type of the argument.

Answer (score 4):

According to what I see in STL source:

`add_cv_t<T>` and `const volatile T`- no difference

`add_const_t<T>` and `const T` - no difference

`add_volatile_t<T>` and `volatile T` - no difference

`add_lvalue_reference_t<T>` and `T&` - there is difference for example if T is non referenceable type void. `add_lvalue_reference_t<void>::type = void` and `void&` = compile-time error

`add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` and `T&&` - the same as above

`add_pointer_t<T>` and `T*` - difference when T is reference, because there is no such thing as pointer to reference. `add_pointer_t<T>` is equivalent to `std::remove_reference<T>::type*`

Comment: Interesting, what is the reason to downvote this answer?

Comment: The compile-time error is uncertain. In some implementations no error occur

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` is equivalent to `T&&`. However, [reference collapsing rules](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) and the-rules-that-dictate-which-types-are-referenceable may have your code misbehave if not taked into account.

There are, however, some cases where the `type` static member type will be different due to `T` being a non-referenceable type. For example `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<void>` resolves to `void`, and (taking another template you mentioned as an example) `std::add_pointer_t<T&>` resolves to `T*` (if you want to invoke chaos, the required ritual is `std::add_pointer_t<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<void>>` :))

Respecting to uses, it may be used as a template template parameter to do some funky black magic. Anyway, stuff like [`std::is_rvalue_reference_t<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_rvalue_reference) or [`std::remove_reference_t<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) is usually more commonly used when manipulating the type's reference attributes.

Comment: It's simply better to say "probably" rather to assert something that may (somehow) not be the case. The point behind that and "his/her opinion", is that the OP isn't specifing what (or rather, *why*) is he/she doing it. Is it simple theory? Or rather, as I call it, "black magic"? We don't know, and reference collapsing rules can pretty much affect whether his/her code misbehaves (if not taken into account).

Comment: BTW, I edited again. With the previous edit, the first paragraph became non-sense, and so @Barry had his point with it.

Comment: How do alias templates affect reference collapsing?

Comment: You probably meant "how do reference collapsing affect alias templating?", which at its own should be rephrased to "how do reference collapsing affect templates?". Well, the answer is a bit complex and should be addressed on another question.